# Transforming XML into JSON loadable structure for BigQuery

Tags: python, json, xml, google-bigquery

I’m learning python on the job and need help improving my solution.

I need to load XML data into **BigQuery**.

I have it working but not sure if I have done it in a sensible way.

I call an API that returns an XML structure.
I use **ElementTree** to parse the XML and use **tree.iter()** to return the tags and text from the XML.
Printing my tags and text with:

```
for node in tree.iter():
    print(f'{node.tag}, {node.text}')
```

Returns:

```
Tag              Text
Responses        None
Response         None
ResponseId       393
ResponseText     Please respond “Has this loaded” 
ResponseType     single
ResponseStatus   0
```

The **Responses** tag appears only once per API call but **Response** through to **ResponseStatus** are   repeating groups, **ResponseId** is the key for each group. Each call would return less than a 100 repeating groups.

There is a key returned in the header, **Response_key**, that is the parent of all **ResponseIds**.
My aim is to take this data, convert to JSON and stream to BigQuery.

The table structure I need is:

**ResponseKey, ResponseID, Response, ResponseText, ResponseType , ResponseStatus**

The  approach  I use is

1. Use tree.iter()  to loop and create a list

   ```
   node_list = [] 
   for node in tree.iter():    
   node_list.append(node.tag)
   node_list.append(node.text)
   ```
2. Use itertools to group the list (this I found a difficult step)

   ```
   r = 'Response '        
   response _split = [list(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(node_list, lambda z: 
       z == r) if not x]
   ```

which returns:

```
[['Responses', 'None'], ['None', 'ResponseId', '393', 'ResponseText', Please respond “Has this loaded” 
"', 'ResponseType', 'single', 'ResponseStatus', '0'], ['None', 'ResponseId', '394', 'ResponseText', Please confirm “Connection made” "', 'ResponseType', 'single', 'ResponseStatus', '0']]
```

3. Load into a Pandas data frame, remove any double quotes in case that causes BigQuery any issues.
4. Add ResponseKey as a column to the dataframe.
5. Convert data frame to JSON and pass to **load_table_from_json**.

It works but not sure if it is sensible.

Any suggested improvements would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
{"GetResponses":"<Responses><Response><ResponseId>393938<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Please respond to the following statement:\"The assigned task was easy to complete\"<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393939<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Did you save your  datafor later? Why\/why not?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>1<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393940<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Did you notice how much it cost to find the item? How much was it?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393941<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Did you select ‘signature on form’? Why\/why not?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>1<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393942<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Was it easy to find thethe new page? Why\/why not?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>1<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393943<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Please enter your email. So that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task.<\/ResponseText><ResponseShortCode>email<\/ResponseShortCode><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>1<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393944<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Why didn't you save your  datafor later?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393945<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Why did you save your  datafor later?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393946<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Did you save your  datafor later?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393947<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Why didn't you select 'signature on form'?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393948<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Why did you select 'signature on form'?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>text<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>4444449<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Did you select ‘signature on form’?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393950<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Why wasn't it easy to find thethe new page?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393951<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Was it easy to find thethe new page?<\/ResponseText><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><Response><ResponseId>393952<\/ResponseId><ResponseText>Please enter your email addressSo that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task<\/ResponseText><ResponseShortCode>email<\/ResponseShortCode><ResponseType>single<\/ResponseType><ResponseStatus>0<\/ResponseStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Response><\/Responses>"}
```

A sample JSON without all the processing steps:

```
node_list = []
for node in tree.iter():
    node_list.append(node.tag)
    node_list.append(node.text)

json_format = json.dumps(node_list )
print(json_format)


["Responses", null, "Response", null, "ResponseId", "393938", "ResponseText", Please respond to the following statement:\"The assigned task was easy to complete"", "ResponseType", "single", "ResponseStatus", "0", "ExtendedType", "0"]
```

Comment: can you add an example XML input and JSON output?, it looks like you can iterate threw the XML and copy it to JSON without all the steps in the middle

Comment: Hi @trigonom, thanks for looking at this. I have added the XML and JSON. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the required outpot,
this is one way of doing it

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

p = r"d:\tmp.xml"
tree = ET.parse(p)

root = tree.getroot()

json_dict = {}

json_dict[root.tag] = root.text

json_dict['response_list'] = []


for node in root:
    tmp_dict = {}
    for response_info in node:
        tmp_dict[response_info.tag] = response_info.text
    json_dict['response_list'].append(tmp_dict)

with open(r'd:\out.json', 'w') as of:
    json.dump(json_dict, of)
```

Comment: Hi @trigonom, thanks so much for your help, that is a more elegant solution. Gives me the correct data structure for streaming into BigQuery.